# AttributeError when using hard voting from voting classifier, machine learning, python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, attributeerror

I am trying to use random forest classifier, logistic regression and SVC in a voting classifier (hard voting), but I encounter an error saying: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC

log_clf = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs', random_state = 42)
rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 42)
svm_clf = SVC(gamma = "scale", random_state = 42)

voting_clf = VotingClassifier(estimators = [('lr', log_clf), ('rf', rnd_clf), ('svc', svm_clf)], 
                              voting = 'hard')

y_train_raveled = y_train.ravel()
voting_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_raveled)
```

Here is my X_train and y_train:

```
>>> X_train

array([[-1.00334117e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
         1.30000000e+01,  4.20000000e+01,  5.60000000e+01],
       [-6.94836737e-03,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
         8.00000000e+00,  4.90000000e+01,  1.90000000e+01],
       [-7.61506695e-02,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
         1.40000000e+01,  3.30000000e+01,  5.00000000e+01],
       ...,

>>> y_train.ravel()
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.])
```

This error comes up. I already use standardScaler() to scale the numerical data and use OrdinalEncoder() to convert categorical data. Could anyone please tell me what I did wrong?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-5836b28a28cb> in <module>
      1 y_train_raveled = y_train.ravel()
----> 2 voting_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_raveled)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    220         transformed_y = self.le_.transform(y)
    221 
--> 222         return super().fit(X, transformed_y, sample_weight)
    223 
    224     def predict(self, X):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
     66                 delayed(_parallel_fit_estimator)(clone(clf), X, y,
     67                                                  sample_weight=sample_weight)
---> 68                 for clf in clfs if clf not in (None, 'drop')
     69             )
     70 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_base.py in _parallel_fit_estimator(estimator, X, y, sample_weight)
     34             raise
     35     else:
---> 36         estimator.fit(X, y)
     37     return estimator
     38 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1599                       penalty=penalty, max_squared_sum=max_squared_sum,
   1600                       sample_weight=sample_weight)
-> 1601             for class_, warm_start_coef_ in zip(classes_, warm_start_coef))
   1602 
   1603         fold_coefs_, _, n_iter_ = zip(*fold_coefs_)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in _logistic_regression_path(X, y, pos_class, Cs, fit_intercept, max_iter, tol, verbose, solver, coef, class_weight, dual, penalty, intercept_scaling, multi_class, random_state, check_input, max_squared_sum, sample_weight, l1_ratio)
    938             n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
    939                 solver, opt_res, max_iter,
--> 940                 extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
    941             w0, loss = opt_res.x, opt_res.fun
    942         elif solver == 'newton-cg':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py in _check_optimize_result(solver, result, max_iter, extra_warning_msg)
    241                 "    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/"
    242                 "preprocessing.html"
--> 243             ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
    244             if extra_warning_msg is not None:
    245                 warning_msg += "\n" + extra_warning_msg

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: The version is 0.22.1

Comment: I don't get your error if i try it with sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer , something in your training data?

Comment: I am on sklearn 0.24.1

Comment: My friend uses his MacBook to run my program, and he did not get the error as well. I am using windows. Do you think the error comes from the window system?

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version of sklearn

Comment: I upgraded sklearn, and it works now. Thanks for the suggestion!